# URL mod-rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I want to mod_rewrite this Url:

**Before:**

```
website.altervista.org/page.php?name=value
```

**After:**

```
website.altervista.org/value
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

---

*Explanation:*

The mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` has 3 parameters:

1. Pattern
2. Substitution
3. Flags

Implemented as such:

```
RewriteRule pattern substitution [flags]
```

Starting at server root, enter the requested URL path in the `RewriteRule` "pattern" parameter, and the desired path in the "substitution" parameter. In this case:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

If the URL varies and you don't want to (or can't) write a rule for every situation then use the regular expression `^(.+)$` to capture the dynamic value and inject it into your substituted path using the RE capture variable `$1`. The first set of parenthesis is `$1`, the second set is `$2`, etc. And capturing parenthesis can be nested.

`^(.+)$` This regular expression can be read as: `^` at the start of the string, `$` all the way to the end of the string, look for `.` any character `+` one or times and `()` capture that value into a variable.

---

*Problem:*

Even though we have the flag `[L]` (last rule evaluated), the mod_rewrite engine (behind the scenes) sends the newly constructed request `/page.php?name=somevalue` back through the mod_rewrite engine until no rules are met or, apparently, there are no changes to the request. Fortunately  there is a supplimentary directive to expand on the conditional power provided by the `RewriteRule` called `RewriteCond`.

The mod_rewrite `RewriteCond` applies to the next occurring `RewriteRule` and also has 3 parameters:

1. Test String
2. Conditional Pattern
3. Flags (optional)

The Test String can be derived from a few sources. Often a Server Variable, relating to the current request, is used here as the subject of this condition.

The Conditional Pattern is, again, text or a regular expression, but has some additional special conditions that may be evaluated. Read the [Apache online mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for a detailed explanation.

In this case: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?name=$1 [L]`, our newly substituted request is sent back through mod_rewrite as `/page.php?name=somevalue` and matches our "catch-all" rule, therefore our original "somevalue" is lost and replaced with our newly requested resource `page.php`. To prevent our "catch all" from catching our "page.php" requests let's exclude it from the rule using `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This `RewriteCond` can be read as: `%{REQUEST_URI}` get the requested resource and does it `!` NOT `$` end with `page.php`. If this condition is true, continue to the next condition or rule. If this condition is not true, skip this rule set and continue to the next rule set.